# Getting compiler error 'binary '<<' : no operator found' in VS 2005

Tags: c++, xml, exception, type-conversion, operator-overloading

I am getting the below compiler error when I build my project:

XMLHelper.h(22) : error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'COSB::AnyException' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Code of XMLHelper.h:

```
 class XMLException : public COSB::Exception

{
public:
    XMLException(const MSXML2::IXMLDOMParseErrorPtr &verr, const char *prefix_description="XML error")
        : Exception(verr->errorCode)
    {
/*line 22  error line */
*this << prefix_description << " " << std::hex << long(verr->errorCode) << std::dec;
   ...}
```

XMLHelper.h is not directly part of my project. I checked the exception.h which has below function definition:

```
class ExceptionBase : public std::exception
{ ...}

// Any exception including Win32 structured exceptions and COSB::Exception.
class AnyException: public ExceptionBase
{
public:

  // This insertion operator needed to be declared as a member function or the 
  //compiler gets confused as to which template function to apply.
     // Notice that stateful stream manipulators like width will probably not 
  //work

AnyException &operator<<( std::ostream& (_cdecl *f)(std::ostream&) )
{
    ExceptionBufferStream buf(FormatHolder());
    (*f)(buf);
    AppendToDescription(buf.c_str(),buf.LineSize());
    return  *this;
    }
   ..}
```

How to resovle this error?

Thanks 
Raghu

Comment: The member `operator<<` takes a function pointer as parameter. Can't see any operator taking a `const char*`. Apparently the compiler doesn't see one either.

Comment: The below fucntion is also defined - template <> inline COSB::AnyException &operator<<(COSB::AnyException &x, const char * const &s) { x.AppendToDescription(s); return x; }

Comment: if i change the error line #22 to :*this << prefix_description; then there is no compiler error.

Comment: Then another problem is that [std::hex and std::dec](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) works on `ios_base` and not `ostream`. So the function pointer type doesn't match.